# Facebook Follow Button counter always show 0

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, counter

I have a simple website with "Like" and "Follow" buttons. The "Like" button counter works fine, it shows me the correct number, but the "Follow" button shows 0. I know my fb page have more than 1 followers.

The site with the buttons: http://hispan.hu/photos.php
The FB-site behind the counter: https://www.facebook.com/hispansphotoblog

Is it my fault, or FB problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Followers* are people subscribed to a feed, which your Page does not have.

You are after the [Like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) button.